# How to convert pandas data frame into list of tuples<string, list of list>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which has a following structure

```
title      field1    field2   field3    field4   field5
title1    value11    value12  value13    value14   value15
title1    value21    value22  value23    value24   value25
title1    value31    value32  value33    value34   value35
title2    value1_1    value1_2  value1_3    value1_4   value1_5
title2    value2_1    value2_2  value2_3    value2_4   value2_5
title2    value3_1    value3_2  value3_3    value3_4   value3_5
```

I want to convert above data frame into a list  of tuples<String, List of List>,

For example,

```
title1, [
    (value11, value12, value13, value14, value15),
    (value21, value22, value23, value24, value25),
    (value31, value32, value33, value34, value35)
]
title2, [
    (value1_1, value1_2, value1_3, value1_4, value1_5),
    (value2_1, value2_2, value2_3, value2_4, value2_5),
    (value3_1, value3_2, value3_3, value3_4, value3_5)
]
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @PaulH I want to convert this df to list of Pydantic base models where model has two fields title and list of list of fields .

Comment: @abhijeet What is `titl1`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh typo mistake...fixed now

Comment: @abhijeet Is there any further clarification required on my answer ?  If no, please review whether you would like to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tuple()` inside lambda function in [`df.GroupBy.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) as follows:

Assuming the fields columns are from the 2nd column onwards. If not, you can modify the column index range in `df.columns[1:]` below or explicitly use list the columns names below:

```
(df.groupby('title')[df.columns[1:]]
   .apply(lambda x: [tuple(y) for y in x.to_numpy()])
   .to_dict())
```

Result:

```
{'title1': [('value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 'value15'),
  ('value21', 'value22', 'value23', 'value24', 'value25'),
  ('value31', 'value32', 'value33', 'value34', 'value35')],
 'title2': [('value1_1', 'value1_2', 'value1_3', 'value1_4', 'value1_5'),
  ('value2_1', 'value2_2', 'value2_3', 'value2_4', 'value2_5'),
  ('value3_1', 'value3_2', 'value3_3', 'value3_4', 'value3_5')]}
```